# What are aggregate classes for?

Tags: c++

I have just read the following definition in **C++ Primer** (5th edition) on page 298:

> A class is an aggregate if:
>
> - All of its data members are public
> - It does not define any constructors
> - It has no in-class initializers
> - It has no base classes or virtual functions

A definition is also provided in this post: [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special).

After all I read in the previous sections of the book on the value of encapsulation, I am wondering: why would anyone want to use an aggregate class? (BTW, the question seems to be applicable to `struct` in general: why would I want to have `public:` by default?)

Comment: Why not? In other words, what's your effort to answer the question?

Comment: Why not? Encapsulation! Item 22 of **Effective C++** (3rd edition) is titled: "Declare data members private"!

Comment: @Meir Goldenberg An aggregate in turn can be a private data member of some class.:)

Comment: So, why encapsulation, I could ask? C++ is a multi-paradigm language that can be used for more than just object-based programming. Also, programming implies choice. An informed programmer can decide which technique is applicable and which isn't. BTW: The advise to declare data members private is just that, an advise. It's not an absolute must.

Comment: `struct` must have default visibility `public` for compatibility with C.  And often times it is very useful, especially with template meta-programming where we use `static` members as a way to “return” stuff.  If you don't like it, simply use `class` instead of `struct`.

Comment: The premise of this question appears to be "everything should be 'encapsulated' even though I don't understand what encapsulation means and have sucked up every lie and myth about OOP that my University professors threw at me ... and even though I haven't found out yet that C++ is not an OO language". No offence.

Answer (score 10):

An aggregate is basically a simple collection of data that does not have any invariants the `class` would have to guarantee. Since there is no invariant and thus all combinations of possible values of the member make sense, there is no point in making them private since there is nothing to protect.

A simple example for such a class would be something like

```
struct Point3d {
   std::array<double, 3> coordinates;
};
```

Since every triple of `double`s is a point in R^3, there is nothing to gain by hiding the data. (If you are afraid of `NaN` and `infinity` values, this might not be the best idea. If this can happen, you might want to not make this an aggregate.)

Another example of an aggregate type is [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Again, it is just an array of some type and some (immutable) length, so no invariant is to protect.

One advantage of aggregates is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: I think that the `aggregate class` in C++ seems to be the same as `struct` in C. Am I right?

Comment: @zhenguoli Not quite. While every C-struct is an aggregate, the converse does not hold. Aggregates may have base classes and member functions with some restrictions, for a complete list see the link at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it.

Answer (score 6):

Aggregate classes can be aggregate initialized using an initializer list:

```
struct Agg {
    string a;
    int b;
}
Agg a = {"A string", 0};
```

They are mainly used as a tupple-like return value like so:

```
struct Response {
    bool success;
    string body; // Body is only set if success is true
}

Response foo() {
    if(failed) return {false, ""};
    return {true, "content"};
}
```

As you can see all four requirements have to be fulfilled for this to be meaningful (before c++11).

> All of its data members are public

It's pretty much just a tuple of objects.

> It does not define any constructors

Well, either you initialize all members (via aggregate initialization) or you default initialize all members (with the default constructor).

> It has no in-class initializers

Same as above

> It has no base classes or virtual functions

It's tuple-like, so base classes would destroy that and virtual functions don't make sense since you wouldn't inherit from such a class.

I hope this clears it up a bit. Remember that this is was invented before C++11 where `std::tuple` wouldn't exist so you would have used an aggregate class to return multiple values. Nowadays in most use cases you could use `tuple` aswell but it is not my favorite.

---

### `std::tuple` vs aggregate classes

- An aggregate class can define member functions
- An aggregate class can overload operators.
- An aggregate can define useful names for its attributes
- etc.. to expand

Most of the time, aggregate classes are the way to go. tuple should only be used if you really want nothing else but returning a tuple of objects, and then "breaking it into its pieces". Member functions don't make sense most of the time but aggregate classes can still overload the cast operator for example.

Use tuples only when you only want to do nothing but retuning a bunch of objects together, without a need to "name" them (via member names in aggregates)

Comment: Are you saying that std::tuple makes aggregate classes deprecated?

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg It can be substituted in most cases, yes. But `std::tupple` may need more memory and doesn't support member functions.

Comment: Why can std::tuple be preferable?

Comment: _"But `std::tupple` may need more memory"_ Why's that?

Comment: @WorldSEnder . You specify the following rule: "All of its data members are public." You're classes ( Agg  and Response ) do not seem to respect this requirement and yet you call it aggregate. Why?

Comment: @GabrielGrigoras my best guess about what I meant 5 years ago is that those should be structs, not classes :)